# Trying to programatically add div with spans within to a div on an asp.net page. Getting errors/null references

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a dynamic number of data elements that need to be added to my asp.net page. I am currently trying to do this by looping through a result data set like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserDB db = new UserDB();
    string employeeIDOrName = Request.QueryString["employeeID"];
    DataSet ds = db.GetUserSearch(employeeIDOrName);
    DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        string employeeID = row[0].ToString();
        string emailAddress = row[1].ToString();
        string phone = row[2].ToString();
        string details = emailAddress + " | " + phone;

        UserControl uc = new Controls_EmployeeSearchResults(employeeID, details);
        placeholder1.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
}
```

Then in the employeeSearchResults code, I have:

```
<div class="returnDataBoxSup" onclick="insertAddedSup('1091912','Shawna Burns');">
    <div id="searchResults" runat="server">

    </div>
</div>
```

for the ascx page and

```
public Controls_EmployeeSearchResults(string name, string details)
{
    /*<div class="returnDataBoxSup" style="overflow:hidden;" onclick="insertAddedSup('1091912','Shawna Burns');">

    <span ID="spanName" runat="server" style="text-transform:capitalize; white-space:nowrap"></span><br />
    <span ID="spanDetails" runat="server" style="font-size:0.7em; white-space:nowrap"></span>
</div>*/
    //Div
    HtmlGenericControl div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div1.ID = "returnDataBoxSup";
    div1.Attributes["style"] = "overflow:hidden;";
    div1.Attributes["onClick"] = "insertAddedSup('1091912','Shawna Burns');";
    div1.Attributes["class"] = "returnDataBoxSup";

    //Span Name
    HtmlGenericControl span1 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
    span1.ID = "span_" + name;
    span1.Attributes["style"] = "text-transform:capitalize; white-space:nowrap";
    span1.InnerHtml = name;

    //Span Details
    HtmlGenericControl span2 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
    span2.ID = "spanD_" + name;
    span2.Attributes["style"] = "font-size:0.7em; white-space:nowrap";
    span2.InnerHtml = details;

    div1.InnerHtml = span1.ToString();
    div1.InnerHtml += span2.ToString(); ;
    //div1.Controls.Add(span1);
    //div1.Controls.Add(span2);
    //searchResults = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    searchResults.InnerHtml = div1.ToString();
}
```

in the code behind. I first tried to add the span controls to the div, but I was receiving an exception. When I tried to add the controls to the inner html, it said that it could not convert the control type to string. Is there any way that I can do what I am trying to do?

I receive employee data in a data set, then I want to loop through those and create a stylized div for each employee record and display it on my page. Any thoughts?

Comment: Many questions to your code: what is `placeholder1`, `searchResults`? Where do you implement your control? Why not to use ListView for your purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the user control isn't a bad idea, using a ListView could be a lot better/easier though.

But lets say you stick with a div and a user control for now.  Firstly, you don't create usercontrols the same way you create other controls because you are part way through the page life cycle and they need to be caught up.  Instead use LoadControl (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786121/328968).

Second, don't pass the values into the constructor.  Create a function in your usercontrol called LoadData and pass the values to that.  After creating your usercontrol using LoadControl you call LoadData and pass in the values.  LoadData takes care of loading the data into the various controls which, unlike your example, should probably already exist in your usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Try the InnerText to see if it works.